# RSS news reader

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I was able to create a RSS reader but it needs to run a separate server for the RSSparser and such. I want to know if it is possible to automatically run this server when I use the command npm start, instead of

So for example;
I have to run local host 4000 for the server before I can even get the items in local host 3000 to appear. Is there a way where I would just click on npm start and both instance would run?

```
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import RSSParser from "rss-parser";

const feedURL = "https://yaleclimateconnections.org/feed/";
const parser = new RSSParser();
let articles = [];

const parse = async url => {
    const feed = await parser.parseURL(url);

    feed.items.forEach(item => {
        articles.push({ item })
    })
}

parse(feedURL);

let app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(articles);
})

const server = app.listen("4000", () => {
    console.log("App is listening at http://localhost:4000");
})

export default server;
```

I would run this first by npm start on the folder it is in, then run the main. Is there a way to get it to me just doing npm start on the whole directory and it would run both?

project directory

- server
- src

I tried running it on
./project directory npm start

does not work
only runs SRC codes but the server for RSS wont show.
please help